# Excel VBA Paste Error "...isn't the same size..."

Tags: vba, excel

NB: I'm brand new to VBA and code in general

I've attempted to make a macro that collates data from multiple workbooks and imports it into a master workbook ('ZMaster').

The following code successfully copies data from the cell C5 in multiple workbooks (from file C:\AutoMelinh) and pastes them in a column in my 'ZMaster' workbook.

The issue is I get the error 'The data you are pasting isn't the same size as your selection. Do you want to paste anyway?'. This comes after every paste, so I have to click 'ok' every single time. The format of the cell that is copied, is merged (between C5 and D5). I think this is the issue however I don't know how to mitigate that in the VBA code:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = "C:\AutoMelinh\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "ZMaster.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Range("C5").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
    MyFile = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

EDIT: I was able to solve the issue by using

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = "C:\AutoMelinh\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "ZMaster.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Range("C5").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
    MyFile = Dir

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by putting in the command:

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Before copying and:

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

After copying

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and then accept your own answer as solution. This way every future readers see that the question has a solution.

Comment: @M.CHA is using merged cells absolutely necessary? You can imitate merge of the cells by removing inner borders and setting horizontal alignment of "merged" cells to `xlCenterAcrossSelection`

Comment: @Peh I will be sure to do that next time

Comment: @AntiDrondert 17 It isn't necessary, but the 600 excel spreadsheets that I have to collate all have merged cells in their template

Comment: select a single cell, not a range of cells, to paste into.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the warning because you are pasting one cell into 4 cells

this should work without using copy/paste

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim Filepath As String
    Filepath = "C:\AutoMelinh\"

    Dim MyFile As String
    MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

    Dim erow As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        If MyFile = "ZMaster.xlsm" Then Exit Sub

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)

        erow = Workbooks("ZMaster.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        erow.Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C5").Value

        if isempty(erow) then erow.value = "----------"

        wb.Close
        MyFile = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that works really well. I'm now having another problem. In some of the sheets I'm taking data from, the cell has no data in it. I need to know when there is a sheet with no data so I need the cell left blank. 

However this macro will just put the next sheets data in the empty cell. How can I leave empty cells when there is no corresponding data? Or at least know when there has been nothing copied across?

Comment: Can I use the ISEMPTY function in some way?

Comment: added line of code.  if you are tracking empty cells, then maybe you need to track workbook names that they came from.